# I want a YouTube search result display activity and when any video clicked, play it in different YouTubePlayer

Tags: android, webview, youtube, youtubeplayer

I am trying to show direct search result activity to webWiew

```
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;


youtubeVideoUrl = "https://m.youtube.com/results?q="+urlQuery;
```

but activity displays black page.
I want to whenever somebody click any video thumbnail just catch the url and play in YouTube Player.

I have used

```
@Override  
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
     youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);               
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kM9Z.png)

Comment: If you only return `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)` then why do you override the method at all?

Comment: oh! i forgot this. Please see it again. When i clicked on any video of  youtube search result the method 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' was bypassed.